# Azure Search Indexers running delays

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have set up a search index that gets updated by multiple indexers that use SQL databases as datasources, particularly SQL views. The most time consuming indexer used to run in ~3min since yesterday when it went up to ~33min. Nothing changed in terms of code (using Net SDK) or in terms of views. I also checked the database in case that was the cause of the delay but the view runs in ~1min (returns 26,894 records). This happens only in the production search service. The corresponding staging indexer in the staging search service continues to run in ~3min. I also tried recreating the indexer but that did not work as well.

Any ideas would be very helpful.

Comment: Couple of questions: Do the indexers have skillsets? Does the stage indexer point to the same datasource as the production indexer? Is the longer than usual indexer run time observed across multiple runs?

Comment: Indexers do not have skillsets, stage indexer points to a different stage datasource, the longer than usual time is observed across multiple runs.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Given the limited data we have, I'll throw out one idea: It could be the SQL query taking longer. The indexer issues a query that sorts by HWM, which may or may not be the same query you've checked with against the view. Depending on the type of HWM column, this sorting can take time. Is it possible to see logs indicating indexer query runtime on your SQL instance?